# How to show notification on android?

Tags: java, android

I have the following function:

```
public void startApp(View v){
        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.a);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("arroz");
        mBuilder.setContentText("LOL ARROZ MASSA");
        mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

I call this function when I click on a button.

I want a notification to appear when I do so, so I used this code, but the notification is not appearing. What am I missing here?

EDIT:

```
public void startApp(View v){
        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.a);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("arroz");
        mBuilder.setContentText("LOL ARROZ MASSA");
        mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        mBuilder.setChannelId("1");
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting notification channel , It might be the reason .Try setting channelId and check

```
 final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID")
 mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.a);
 mBuilder.setContentTitle("arroz");
 mBuilder.setContentText("LOL ARROZ MASSA");
 mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

To notify

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);    
NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID", "CHANNEL_NAME", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build())
```

Comment: I need to send it in API 21. Do you have a solution for that API?

Comment: check updated answer